# Alternative for geom_label in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I would like to use the "fill" function of geom_label in a ggplotly graph. Unfortunately, ggplotly does not support geom_label. Instead I am working with geom_text but you cannot use "fill" here. Is there an alternative of how to get a background around your text without geom_label as in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: If you want to use `ggplotly`, consider the `tooltip` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this mimics the aesthetic of geom_label:

```
#First compute sizes
width <- strwidth(rownames(mtcars),units = "figure")
height <- strheight(rownames(mtcars),units = "figure")
xrange <- diff(range(mtcars$wt))
yrange <- diff(range(mtcars$mpg))

#New dataset
data <- data.frame(x = mtcars$wt,
                   y = mtcars$mpg,
                   label = rownames(mtcars),
                   xmin = mtcars$wt - width*xrange,
                   xmax = mtcars$wt + width*xrange,
                   ymin = mtcars$mpg - height*yrange,
                   ymax = mtcars$mpg + height*yrange)

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y, label = label)) + 
  geom_rect(fill = "white",aes(xmin = xmin,xmax = xmax,ymin = ymin,ymax = ymax)) +
  geom_text() 

ggplotly(gg)
```

[image: plot with car names and white rectangles]

But it's not great. If you zoom in the rectangles will not resize as the text does, so consider whether you can live with that. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplotly(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, text=rownames(mtcars))) + geom_point(), tooltip = "text")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi there is a difference between tooltip and geom_label. I don't want the label only on a mousover. But thank you anyway!